# Which built-in class can be used to notify observer in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-components

Could someone hint on whether Android/Java provides a class to achieve something like this:

Provider.java

```
public Notify<Object> waitNotification() {
   return ...
}
```

Consumer.java

```
public void method() {
    waitNotification().onResult(object -> {
        ...
    });
}
```

I am currently trying to apply Android Architecture Component in new project, and have plenty of `LiveData<T>` as results from repository layers. Now the problem with `LiveData<T>` is that it will provides last value set whenever Activity/Fragment is reactivated.  I want only one-time notification.

PS: I am trying to make the callback pattern consistent, and want to avoid using callback instance pass-in style like this: `public void waitNotification(ICallback callback) { .... }`

Comment: Use an RxJava2 `Single` or `Observable`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Now I get it, the architecture design of my imagination is RxJava2 ahah :D Thanks for your insightful comment :D